# Casting dynamic to int succeeds but 'as int?' returns null

Tags: dynamic, json.net

I am confused by some code results using `dynamic`.

I am parsing some JSON in C# using the Newtonsoft json.net libraries. The JSON string ends like this:

```
}],"Result":{"820":1,"821":1,"822":2,"823":0}}
```

and so I set up a class to contain the parsed JSON:

```
public class Poll
{
    public Answer[] Answer { get; set; }
    public dynamic Result { get; set; }
}
```

and then parse my JSON string with this line

```
var poll = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BallotsharePoll>(json);
```

and then this code to delve into the dynamic object:

```
if (poll.Result["820"] != null)
{
    var votes = (int)(poll.Result["820"]).Value;
    result[i] = votes;
}
```

This works. But my original code used int? and the line

```
var votes = (poll.Result["820"]).Value as int?;
```

which fails as shown in the watch window here:

[image: VS2013 watch window screenshot]

This shows that

- the dynamic value of `poll.Result["820"]` is `{1}`,
- the value of `(int)(poll.Result["820"]).Value` is `1`,
- but the value of `(poll.Result["820"]).Value as int?` is `null`

**QUESTION:** Why does `as int?` return `null` while casting to `int` results in `1`?

I would rather use `int?` to cover the case where the dynamic value cannot be coerced into an `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this program:

```
using System;
static class Program {
  static void Main()     {
    dynamic s = (short)1;
    Console.WriteLine(s as int?);
    Console.WriteLine((int)s);
  }
}
```

The first `WriteLine` prints nothing, the second prints `1`. Likely, the problem in your case is similar.

This is not intuitive behaviour, I'll happily admit. When using `as` with `dynamic`, what you get is pretty much `s is int? ? (int?)s : null`, and `s is int?` would return `false` with or without `dynamic`.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for exhuming a very old question but I know the answer behind this behavior.

To be short, the keyword "int?" is just a shortcut for the generic class Nullable, with the generic type T as Int.

So a dynamic, to be considered an int?, should be a Nullable instance.

if your Json was

```
}],"Result":{"820":{"Value":1,"HasValue":true},}}
```

the operation "as int?" would have worked.